# Best way to transfer data from view to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, hidden-field

I'm working in an Asp.Net MVC 3 project where in one of my javascript file, a message is displayed to the user. This message in currently in one language but I want this message to be in multiples languages. I don't want to store theses languages directly in the javascript file but instead in a database. I want to know if it possible to transfer data (string) from the view to the javascript file.

One solution that I've found is to set data from my view in hidden fields and then extract it from my javascript file. The problem with this solution is that I must put a lot of hidden fields and this is very hard to maintain.

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can try JavaScriptModel ( http://jsm.codeplex.com ).

With this library you can add variables by calling the following function in your controller action:

```
this.AddJavaScriptVariable("VariableNameInJavaScript", SomeValue);
```

You can pass primitive types or complex types.

Furthermore you could execute javascript functions with the following code in your controller action:

```
this.AddJavaScriptFunction("FunctionInJavaScript", SomeParameter, AnotherParameter);
```

Comment: +1 Hum.... I think there is a lack about 'Separation of concerns" with this solution but it will help me preventing the merging of @Model and other stuffs in the script tag and for this reason, this is good.

Comment: Depending how you see the separation of concerns :) This way you separate javascript from the view and you transfer your "javascript model", which are all variables for javascript, to your javascript view, which is client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your on the right path. All you need to do is hydrate your model appropriately and use Razor syntax to pass the value from the server to the client "along the following lines":

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/yourapi.js")"></script>
<script>
    yourapi.foo('@Model.SomeValue');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanx @Xander to trying helping me. I already think about what you suggest but if the javascript is already in cache on the client browser, assigning value from the view will it be transfer? If the javascript file is in the browser cache and the view assign a value server side, this javascript file with the value will never be downloaded by the browser or I could be wrong in my logic?!